# What does “if” mean here? “... if at times depressing”

Tags: meaning

I've just read a phrase in my Cambridge book which is:

> It is compelling, if at times depressing.

My question is about the word *if*: What does it mean, in this case? Could I interpret it as: "It is so compelling that tends to be depressing"?

P.S.: In the book says that "if", in this case, introduces a negative idea.

Comment: I forgot to type "hello".

Comment: Substitute the word 'but' for 'if' and see if it makes sense now.

Comment: Does it help to say that you can substitute 'albeit' here? Or 'even though/if it is'? More precisely, 'if' here introduces a mitigating (contrastive without being negating) statement.

Comment: Thank you, Rattler and Edwin Ashworth. Now I got it!

Comment: No you cannot infer that *if* here means *therefore* or *tends to*. The phrase *if at times* means that it happens once in a while. The equivalent phrase would be "It is compelling, so much so that sometimes it is depressing." You could remove the *if* and say *It is compelling—at times depressing* but you could not use a comma here. The *if* allows the comma and *if at times* should be treated as an idiom.

Comment: @AllanRodrigues The answer depends a little on what **it** is. If **it** is e.g., a film or play, then: It is compelling, if, at times, depressing. -> It is compelling, although, *in some parts [of the story/film/play]), it is* depressing. No semicolon is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *if* in this sentence is roughly equivalent to *however*, as in

> It is compelling, however, it is at times depressing.

Note: Some people might feel that *however* is too strong; this I believe depends on one's personal idiolect.

The Cobuild Grammar (section 8.72) calls this construction a *concessive clause*.

In general, the *if* in that construction implies reservation, as for example:

> Many libraries have little if any control over their patrons.

or introduces a contrast as in

> she was honest, if a little brutal’

Other synonyms (which can be used instead of *if* in this context) are

- although
- albeit
- but
- even though
- even if
- despite being
- in spite of being
- yet
- whilst

(Source: [Lexico Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/if))

So the second clause is a limitation/restriction on the first one. Whatever is compelling, is also sometimes depressing, and that might want you to argue against it.

Comment: I think I would put a semi-colon before 'however'. (https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/389239/could-it-be-correct-to-have-the-word-however-flanked-by-two-commas)

Comment: @Rattler yes, you could.

Comment: Thank you, Oliver Mason! I wouldn´t have had this point of view (the 2nd clause as a limitation on the first one).

Answer (score 4):

*If* is used in that case more like a version of "although" or "even though":

> **if** *conj*
>   2. Although possibly; even though: *It is a handsome if useless trinket*.
>   <sub>[TFD Online](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/if)</sub>

Pay special attention to the robust usage note there.

Comment: Thank you, Robusto!

Comment: @Allan: You realize the answer you accepted is wrong, don't you?

Comment: @Robusto Could you enlighten my as to why it is wrong?

Comment: @Allan: Because *if* doesn't baldly mean *however*. *However* is a direct contradiction, and the way *if* is used in this case is more nuanced. It grants the possibility that a thing  may be useless without stressing that point.

Comment: @Robusto Sorry, I disagree. _However_ is not a direct contradiction, and is perfectly adequate to express the nuance in this case.

Comment: Anyway, I have to say thank you for both, as you all helped me to get the idea.